# sed: unterminated 's' command`

Tags: regex, bash, sed, git-bash

I'm writing a nice regex to replace some IP's in a text file.

```
sed -r "s/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/${APP_IP}/g" /path/to/my/file
```

However it is giving: `sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unterminated 's' command`

I need the double quotes otherwise it replaces desired strings with the literal variable name: ${APP_IP}

What am I missing?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue - what is the value of `APP_IP`?

Comment: The problem is likely going to be a `/`, newline, or other terminating character present in `$APP_IP`.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me :)

Comment: Seems to be working when I set the variable manually to the desired IP. If I capture the IP from a variable it fails. Must be special characters in the variable. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Seems to be working when I set the variable $APP_IP manually to the IP under test. If I capture the variable from the output (of a ping) it gives the error. Must be special characters in the variable. Thanks guys.

Comment: Does the output include a newline?

Comment: Yes, I took it out using APP_IP=$(echo $APP_IP | tr -d '\n') and it worked :)

Comment: You can just do  APP_IP=$(echo -n "$APP_IP")